# In java is it possible to pack a integer number that is expected not to be negative & be final (not overflow) into a short?

Tags: java, integer, packing, short

"Unsigned int" into a short and back. Is this possible? How to do it if so?

Grrrr. I forgot how signed numbers are implemented. The question makes no sense. Thanks anyway. I was going to downvote myself, you can do it instead.

Comment: an 'unsigned int' has no meaning in java. You can be either talking about an integer that has only 'positive' values, but still in the int range (a 31 bit number), or a full 32 bit unsigned int, which has a range of 0->(MAX_INT*2) on java. Neither will fit in a java short. A java short is still a signed number, with a max value of 2^15-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but if you are sure that your int fit into a short (you number is between 0 and 2^16) you can always cast your int to a short:

```
int i = 65536;
short s = (short) i;
```

And to get the unsigned value back:
    int i2 = s & 0xFFFF;
    System.out.println(i2);

The `s & 0xFFFF` will upcast s to an int and the bit mask will "convert" the negative number to it's unsigned value (sort of). Remember that FFFF in a short variable -1 not 65536.

Comment: Thanks, this will work, on a reduced range but it seems the best possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're hoping for a basic type that'll do the work for you, but I don't think one exists.  On the other hand, I don't imagine it would be too difficult to create an object that does the work.  Adjust as necessary to make it a short.

```
public class SpecialInt {
 int i = 0;

 public void set(int i) {
  if ( i < 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot be negative");
  this.i = i;
 }

 public void add(int j) {
  int t = i+j;
  if( t < i ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("overflow!");
  i = t;
 }

 public void sub(int j) {
  int t = i-j;
  if( t > i ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("overflow!");
  i = t;
 }

 public void mult(int j) {
  int mult_max = Integer.MAX_VALUE / i;
  if( j > mult_max ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("overflow!");
  i *= j;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your integer number doesn't have any specific characteristic like being a multiple of something I don't think you can.

The problem is that information contained into an int, that usually is 32 bit architecture cannot be contained into a short.

As you can see from `Short.MAX_VALUE` tha maximum value is 2^15 - 1, since a short occupies 16 bit.. so you actually lose precision and you can't express integers like 2²²..

Comment: I'm willing to risk int this case a slightly reduced upper range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unsigned types, you can use the [Javolution](http://javolution.org/) library.